# How to Highlight dynamically loaded menu item in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, menu, menuitem

i am facing some problem with Menu item highlighting on user selection.

I am loading all menu items from database, I used

StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="Item"

StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="ItemSelected"

StaticHoverStyle CssClass="ItemHover"

and

DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="ItemSelected"

But it is not working for me.

Is there suggestions or any ideas please share with me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you sure if the css in your page dosent have errors and is included correctly??

Answer (score 0):

if your menu having `<li>...<a>..</a></li>` structure apply the highlighting on the "li" and add these attributes also:
`<li onmouseout="unselect(this)" onmouseover="select(this)">`
which is handling the mouse events using javascript.
hope that's will help!